# Why does Internet Explorer use text/richtext as MIME type for uploaded RTF files?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, file-upload, mime-types, rtf

According to the Wikipedia entry, the Rich Text format (RTF)

> ... should not be confused with enriched text (mimetype
>   "text/enriched" of RFC 1896) or its predecessor Rich Text (mimetype
>   "text/richtext" of RFC 1341 and 1521) (...) which are completely
>   different specifications.

The Wikipedia entry lists two valid Internet Media Types for Rich Text Format documents: 'text/rtf' and 'application/rtf'.

Internet Explorer 11 however uses "text/richtext" for files with .rtf extension when they are uploaded by a HTML form. Why does IE not use one of the two correct MIME types?

---

Example HTML form code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
... etc (submit button)
</form>
```

Comment: How would it know from only the file extension?

Comment: You mean it should send the file name of every file you're uploading anywhere to an online service?

Comment: I think neither have we, you'd need to ask a microsoft engineer (especially on the "why", not "how does it determine").

Answer (score 1):

You can try these mime types,
application/rtf,
application/x-rtf,
text/rtf, 
text/richtext,
application/msword, 
application/doc,
application/x-soffice

Answer (score 0):

Is turned off by default now; it helps llvm building faster just with the things you declare to build. Is not the exact same for backend, because when you launch cmake there are a list of default targets that are build by default. You can check al these things inside /llvm/CMakeLists.txt file

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I am not sure how this relates to the question